# django flatpages and i18n

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages, django-i18n

I'm trying to choose an approach I'd like to use with some part of the upcoming web-site. The part is ***static content***, which I would usually manage with `django flatpages` framework, that is built in and work great. But the thing is: web site is going to be **i18n** in many ways and ***static content*** is one of them.

For some static content I'm going to use standard django `i18n` package and `.po` files.
Is there a way to make `flatpages` work in i18n way? If no, is there a way to implement that desired approach with some `django-model-i18n-tool`, like [`django-modeltranslation`](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/related_projects.html)?

If all answers is **no**, what is the best practice to work around i18n static content that should be editable from some part of site, preferably admin part?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there *is* the package [`django-flatpages-i18n`](https://github.com/PragmaticMates/django-flatpages-i18n) that even includes a multilanguage menu system. It's pretty small and light-weight but *will* pull some dependencies like `django-mptt`.

Alternatively, you could use one of the Django CMS variants like [`django-cms`](https://www.django-cms.org/%20%60django-cms%60) or [`feincms`](http://www.feincms.org). Both of them are pretty feature-complete and thus quite heavy-weight, and both will pull a number of dependencies.

And finally, you could just use a convention that all English pages start their URL with `en`, and then only link to those. This is the most light-weight but also the feature-poorest solution.